# Splitting a momentum sum between angular and energy integrals

Tags: condensed-matter

When calculating low-energy momentum sums in condensed matter physics (for instance when solving the BCS gap equations), one usually performs the trick of replacing the discrete sum by a continuous integral :

$\frac{1}{V} \sum\limits_{\vec{k}} \mapsto \int \frac{d^3\vec{k}}{(2\pi)^3}$

this continuous limit is justified when the size of the system is large compared to the lattice constant, as the discrete momentum states form a quasi-continuum.

However, in some cases where the only $k$-dependence of the argument lies in the electronic dispersion $\xi_k$ (measured from the Fermi surface) and the system is quasi-2D, one even goes beyond the continuous limit to make the approximation

$\frac{1}{V} \sum\limits_{\vec{k}} \simeq \nu_F \int_{-\Lambda}^{\Lambda} d\xi_k \int d\theta_k$

where $\Lambda$ is a high-energy cutoff of the theory, $\nu_F$ is the density of states at the Fermi level and $\theta_k$ is the angle along the Fermi surface. I understand that $\theta_k$ takes care of the degrees of freedom along the Fermi surface while $\xi_k$ grasps the degrees of freedom orthogonal to the FS.

**Questions :**

- I don't understand how is this change of variables really defined. What happens if the density of states is not a constant ? Is is still valid when the Fermi surface is not circular ?
- I have the feeling that this approximation is only able to capture low-energy features of a given theory. Is this correct ? Is there a way to introduce high-energy features with the same method by working on the cutoff $\Lambda$ ?

Thanks in advance.